# multiple replacements on single line with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, replace

I would like to scan a whole file tree and do two replacements any line with two matches, i.e.:

```
printf("Hello WORLD! %s, %d\n",bcm_errstr(rv),var);
dprintf("kjhgjkhfkhgfjgd %s\n",bcm_errstr(rv));
```

should become

```
printf("Hello WORLD! %d, %d\n",rv,var);
dprintf("kjhgjkhfkhgfjgd %d\n"rv);
```

I tried the following without success (`sed.c` being my test file containing two lines that will match the query):
`p$ grep printf | grep "%s" | grep -rl bcm_errmsg\(rv\) sed.c | xargs sed -i -e 's/%s/%d/' -e 's/bcm_errstr\(rv\)/rv/'`

I use `grep` instead of `find` because the file names are unknown but I'm looking at the file contents instead.

Contents of `sed.c`:

```
 $ cat sed.c  printf("kjhlkjhlkjh%dkjhgljhglj\n",bcm_errmsg(rv)); 
 dprintf("HELLO WORLD %d %d\n",test,bcm_errmsg(rv));
```

i.e. I want to apply the two `sed` replacements only to lines with `printf`, `%s` and `bcm_errstr(rv)` in them.

Comment: Your goal doesn't seem clear to me. Do you just need to change 'bcm_errstr(rv)' to 'rv' in each line where it appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` to get the files recursively and then `sed` to make the changes inline. This should work if I understand your goal correctly:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/%s/%d/g; s/bcm_errstr(rv)/rv/g;'
```

**Note:** that this may match more than you want but you have pretty limited target behavior listed. You'll need to adjust the find part to filter for only the files you are targeting.

Comment: I use `grep` instead of `find` because the file names are unknown but I'm looking at the file contents instead

Comment: Well you look at the contents with sed anyway so you can just drop the `-name`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '/%s/{/bcm_errmsg(rv)/{' -e 's//rv/;s/%s/%d/' -e '}' code.c
```

Provided the things to change are constant, i.e., bcm_errmsg(rv) => rv always.

I like it this way; which makes for quasi-self-documenting code.

```
sed -e '
   /^d\{0,1\}printf(/!b
   /%s/{
      /bcm_errms(rv)/{
         s//rv/
         s/%s/%d/
      }
   }
' code.c
```

Comment: it should only apply to lines where the's a printf (or dprintf).

Comment: @cerr See the updates in the answer section.