# Recursively find files by content

Tags: sed, files, grep, find, recursive

I want to recursively find files in my source tree by contents. I've tried the following using grep:

```
$ grep -rn printf | grep %s | grep bcm_errmsg\(rv\)
```

This returns me every line as I wanted but now, I would like to get the filename of each file that matches, so I changed it to:

```
$ grep -rn printf | grep %s | grep -l bcm_errmsg\(rv\)
```

but instead of printing the filenames, I only get

```
(standard input)
```

printed to stdout. How do I fix this to get each filename & path (to use `sed` on it)?

What I want to do: Find every file with `printf` lines that also contain `%s` and `bcm_errmsg(rv)` and then apply the following sed command to the files found:

```
sed -i 's/%s/%d/g; s/bcm_errmsg(rv)/rv/g;'
```

Comment: Assuming that the order of `printf`, `%s` and `bcm_errmsg(rv)` is unambiguous, you should be able to construct a single regular expression that matches all three in a single `grep`. In fact if you end goal is to edit the matching files in `sed`, I doubt you need `grep` at all - just let `sed` do the pattern matching

Comment: For my GNU `grep` 2.27, the filename is automatically prefixed with option `-r`. Later `grep`ping behind the pipe doesn't remove that path, so your `sed` knows everything before the first `:` is the path.

Comment: @steeldriver please see **EDIT1** above

Comment: Do you want to apply the `sed` commands to every line in files that contain the matching text, or only to the matching lines themselves?

Comment: @cerr What was the problem here: `[https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375525/multiple-replacements-on-single-line-with-sed]` Did that not work ?

Comment: @RakeshSharma for my single test file yes, but not recursively - hence I started a new thread

Comment: @steeldriver the sed command will be applied to the very lines it finds within a particular file, hence it would be on a per file basis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple replacements on single line with sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375525/multiple-replacements-on-single-line-with-sed)

Comment: Should `printf`, `%s` and `bcm_errmsg(rv)` be on the same line or on different lines?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overcomplicating things.  To look for string `foo` in all files located in the current dir and subdirs, simply run

```
grep -r "foo" *
```

By default, grep outputs the matching line prepended by the filename where it was found.

The following will instead only output the filename, without the matching line:

```
grep -rl "foo" *
```

Comment: ... so the latter can't do the additional filter steps that are required in the question

Comment: @steeldriver please see **EDIT1** above

Answer (score 1):

Following @steeldriver's initial idea, you can do:

```
egrep -rl '.*printf.*%s.*bcm_errmsg\(rv\).*' . | xargs -d '\n' sed -i '/printf/ s/%s/%d/; /printf/ s/bcm_errmsg(rv)/rv/'
```

Comment: This almost works only that if there's a `printf` with a `%s` sign, it will replace it with `%d` even if it does not contain `bcm_errmsg(rv)` which is wrong...

Comment: @cerr. Answer updated.

Comment: This selects those files that have a printf, then a %s, and bc_errmsg(v) in that order. It will completely miss out on those files that happen to have these 3 strings in some other order.

Comment: Even the sed command is incorrect in that it does the s/// only on the lines that contain printf. Per OP the subs need to happen only on those lines that contain all  3 strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -rlZP '(?=.*printf)(?=.*%s)(?=.*bcm_errstr\(rv\))' . |
xargs -r0 sed -i -e '
        /%s/!b
        /printf/!b
        /bcm_errstr(rv)/!b
        s/%s/%d/g;s/bcm_errstr(rv)/rv/g
'
```

We first run a recursive dir. from the current dir that scans for files which have the strings: printf, %s, and bcm_errstr(rv) on the same line but maybe in any order. The `grep` options that help us do that are:

- `-r` => will recursively launch on all files in the current dir and below.
- `-l` => will list filenames that match the criteria, viz., all 3 strings on same line.
- `-Z` => the selected filenames are null separated (\0) rather than the usual newline (\n) so that we are able to tackle any kind of filenames.
- `-P` => enable the Perl regex engine whereby we are able to use lookaheads to determine whether the 3 strings are existing on the same line.

On the other side of the pipe, `xargs` is waiting to receive the filenames, separated by \0. It then feeds all these filenames, as much as possible, to sed command line. The sed command you already know from your previous question , where it performs the subs. only on those lines that contain the 3strings on the same line.